# How To Select Data From Generated Information Schema Tables

Tags: sql-server

I have several tables with common table names. I want to select all data from them without specifying all tables and union them. I'm thinking of using information_schema.tables to accomplish this.

Tables:

- tbl_20160201
- tbl_20160202
- tbl_20160203
- tbl_20160204
- tbl_20160205

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'tbl_201602%'
) a
```

However, this query only returns the table names and not the data in the tables. I need to union all the tables included in the query. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these tables have the same number of columns and data types, you can use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'SELECT * FROM ' + TABLE_NAME + ' UNION ALL' + CHAR(10)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'tbl_201602%';

SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql,1, LEN(@sql) - 11);

PRINT(@sql)
EXEC (@sql)
```

Otherwise, you'll get an error saying:

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must
>   have an equal number of expressions in their target lists

Comment: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: by this one we are going to get this error because of all columns are not same for every other table

Comment: OP said: `I have several tables with common table names`. I just assumed these tables have the same data types also.

Answer (score 1):

Below query might help you :-

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @T as sysname 

-- Make sure below temporary table structure same as the tables e.g tbl_201602 which you want to union

declare @TT as Table(     
Col1 [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
Col2 [date] NOT NULL,
Col3 [varchar](200) NOT NULL
)

DECLARE TName CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR  
select TABLE_NAME 
from 
information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME like 'tbl_201602%'

OPEN TName  
FETCH NEXT FROM TName INTO @T 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
   SELECT @SQL = 'select * from' + ' ' + @T    
   INSERT INTO @TT
   EXEC(@SQL)
 FETCH NEXT FROM TName INTO @T   
END  

CLOSE TName  
DEALLOCATE TName

select * from @TT
```

This will give the union of all tables in a single temporary table @TT

NOTE : Just make sure that all comman tables are having same no of columns and in same ordering, otherwise it may raise error